# ValueError at /

Tags: django

The view demo.views.index didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.

```
@csrf_exempt
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        session_id = request.POST.get('sessionId')
        service_code = request.POST.get('serviceCode')
        phone_number = request.POST.get('phoneNumber')
        text = request.POST.get('text')

        response = ""


 if text == "":
            response = "CON What would you want to check \n"
            # response .= "1. My Account \n"
            response += "1. My Phone Number"


        elif text == "1":
            response = "END My Phone number is {0}".format(phone_number)

        return HttpResponse(response)
```

Comment: The error is self-explanatory: your view is returning `None` (not returning anything). Look at all your possible code paths: does every possible code path end with a `return HttpResponse`? The code snippet above doesn't have correct indentations so it's not possible to see where `return HttpResponse` is happening. for example what if `request.method == 'GET'`???

Comment: When asking a question please always describe the problem: What are you doing to make this happen? When does the error occur? e.g. "I'm opening the url so-and-so in the browser, my index page is shown, when I click on button such-and-such it is supposed to submit a form but I get this error: ..." and paste your code as you have it in your text editor, with **the same indentation**.

Answer (score 1):

I guessed your code is not properly indented.

Your Httpresponse is breaking out of elif condition, I assume this is why you are having this error. make sure to always follow convention and adopt best practices.